# Get Mails in small amounts using java mail api

Tags: java, android, email, listview

I am working on a Mailing App in android and i fetch all mails from inbox as well as from folders, but the problem is that fetching is taking too much time to fetch all the mails.

So, i want to fetch mails like this:-

1. Fetch first 20 mails and show them in listview
2. fetch next 20 mails and show all 40 mails in listview and so on....

Now, the problem is that how i can fetch latest 20 mails and then how to keep track of this that i fetch first 20 mails and now fetch next 20 mails from server?

Also, content fetching and arranging at the same time is also making app to take more time to show mails.
How i can decrease the listview filling time?

I can also provide the code for this, if necessary.

Comment: If you have a gmail account with 1000 emails from the last years. Then which ones do you call 'the first 20 mails'?

Comment: First 20 mails means latest mails that i receive in last days.

Comment: But if there are 50 unread or new mails. Which 20 do you want to begin with? The oldest or the newest?

Comment: @greenapps The Newest.

Comment: Ok. Then how do you request the list of emails now? What do you get in?

Comment: @greenapps i used javamail API for this, but i am not getting that how to fetch latest 20, and then more 20 that are after the mails that i fetched.

Comment: That you already told. Such an answer does not help.

Comment: @greenapps what exactly you want to know?